# how to get the row and column indices of the maximum element from a 2D pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

Is there any way that I can retrieve the row and column indices of the greatest element contained in 2-dimensional `pytorch` tensor? For example, see the `pytorch` tensor `a` below:

```py
a
>> torch.tensor([1,2,3],
                [9,5,4],
                [6,7,8])
```

The greatest element in the tensor `a` is 9, which happens at the first column of the second row. If I change that into a python column and row index that starts from zero, the column index  of the element would 0 and the row index would be 1.

Is there any way that I can retrieve the index [1,0] from the 2 dimensional pytorch tensor `a`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no build-in method.
However you could use numpy:

```
np.unravel_index(torch.argmax(a), a.shape)
```

Otherwise you need to write your own logic, something like:

```
def unravel_index(flat_idx, shape): 
     multi_idx = [] 
     r = flat_idx 
     for s in shape[:-1]: 
         multi_idx.append(r // s) 
         r = r % s 
     multi_idx.append(r % s) 
     return multi_idx
```